# Напишите метод, который принимает массив как аргумент и возвращает N

Tags: python, массивы

Вам задан массив, который содержит целые числа. Массив полностью состоит из целых четных или нечетных чисел, за исключением одного числа N. Напишите метод, который принимаем массив, как аргумент и возвращает число N.

Например:

- Вход `[2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]`
- Выход `11`
- Вход `[160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]`
- Выход `160`

Сам думал в таком ключе:

```
array_1 = [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
for n in array_1:
    if n % 2 != 0:
        print(n)
array_2 = [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
for m in array_2:
    if m % 2 == 0:
        print(m)
```

Но чего-то не хватает.

Comment: А чем число N отличается от остальных?

Comment: В смысле чего-то не хватает? По идее то верно, оно ответ неправильный выдает или что?

Comment: Кроме нужного ответа, Выдает еще 3 числа на каждый массив.

Comment: У вас ещё ошибка тут 
for m in array_2:
    if n % 2 == 0:
Разве вместо n не должно быть?

Comment: Вы правы, пропустил этот момент.

Comment: Опечатка n -> m приводила к ошибке. Dima Lol, благодарю.

Comment: Нужно добавить проверку на то какого типа массив. Например логичнее всего проверить первые три числа. Можно считать некоторую сумму прибавляя 1 если число нечетное. Если сумма больше 1 значит массив нечетный и наоборот. Дальше вы уже знаете.

Comment: Как вы узнали (в коде предложенного вопроса), что первый массив почти полностью из чётных, и второй из нечётных чисел? Глазами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз нормальные варианты уже написали, предложу другие :)

*Через фильтрацию:*

```
def foo(items):
    odd = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, items))
    if len(odd) == 1:
        return odd[0]

    even = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, items))
    return even[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    items = [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
    print(foo(items))  # 11

    items = [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
    print(foo(items))  # 160
```

*Через словарь:*

```
from collections import defaultdict


def foo(items):
    bool_by_items = defaultdict(list)

    for i in items:
        bool_by_items[i % 2 == 1].append(i)

    odd = bool_by_items[True]
    if len(odd) == 1:
        return odd[0]

    even = bool_by_items[False]
    return even[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    items = [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
    print(foo(items))  # 11

    items = [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
    print(foo(items))  # 160
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю до кучи своё в некотором роде универсальное решение (никаких `if`-ов, например):

```
def find_rare_item(arr):
    d = {}
    for x in arr:
        i = x % 2
        d[i] = d.get(i, [])
        d[i].append(x)
    return min(d.values(), key=lambda x: len(x))

array_1 = [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
print(*find_rare_item(array_1))

array_2 = [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
print(*find_rare_item(array_2))
```

Вывод:

```
11
160
```

Суть:

- Кладём элементы в список в словаре по ключу "чёт/нечёт"
- Ищем, в каком из этих списков получилось меньше элементов
- Выводим этот редкий элемент (или элементы)

Метод действительно универсальный:

- Он может работать не только по принципу `чёт`/`не чёт`, но и по любому другому принципу
- Число редких/частых элементов тут не важно, выводится столько редких элементов, сколько есть в наличии

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]

even = [i for i in array if i %2 == 0]     # Все   чётные числа из array
odd  = [i for i in array if i %2 == 1]     # Все нечётные числа из array

# Бывод первого елемента из списка, который содержит только один элемент

if len(even) == 1:
    print(even[0])
else:
    print(odd[0])
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 11
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так?

```
def name(list, chet):
   if chet:
       otvet = [a for a in list if a % 2 != 0][0]
   else:
       otvet = [a for a in list if a % 2 == 0][0]
   return otvet
```

Answer (score 0):

еще, как вариант:

```
array_1 = [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
c = [i%2 for i in array_1]
print(min(array_1, key=lambda x: c.count(x%2)))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]